# Toggling a form-horizontal input and its label using shinyjs

Tags: jquery, html, r, shiny, shinyjs

The app below has two selectInputs (`month_abbr` and `month_full`) and a checkboxInput (`abbr`). I would like to hide `month_abbr` *and its label* when `abbr` is `FALSE` and hide `month_full` *and its label* when `abbr` is `TRUE`. I am using the `selector` argument in `shinyjs::toggle` to select each form element but the selector I am using `$('#element').parent('.form-group')` doesn't work.

I thought this may be because the selectInputs themselves have the `form-group` class (`form-group shiny-input-container`), so perhaps the selector only selects the input and not the label tag that I manually created in the form. But this doesn't seem to be the case since the selector doesn't work for the selectInputs either.

The screenshot below shows that both selectInputs are visible regardless of the value of the checkboxInput:

[image]

The app:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui<-shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    tags$form(
      class = "form-horizontal", action="/action_page.php",

      div(
        class = 'form-group', 
        tags$label(class = 'control-label col-sm-2', `for` = 'month_abb', 'Month (abbr.)'),
        div(
          class = 'col-sm-4', 
          selectInput('month_abb', '', month.abb)
        )
      ), 

      div(
        class = 'form-group', 
        tags$label(class = 'control-label col-sm-2', `for` = 'month_full', 'Month (full)'),
        div(
          class = 'col-sm-4', 
          selectInput('month_full', '', month.name)
        )
      ), 

      checkboxInput('abbr', 'Abbreviated')

    )
  )
)

server<-function(input, output) {

  observe({

    toggle(selector = "$('#month_full').parent('.form-group')", condition = !input$abbr)

    toggle(selector = "$('#month_abbr').parent('.form-group')", condition = input$abbr)

  })

}


shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Other selectors I have tried:

- `$('#month_full').parentsUntil('form.form-horizontal')` - I don't know why this didn't work?
- `$('#month_full input label')` (trying to select both the input and the label).

Selecting only the input via its ID (`selector = "#month_full"`) hides the selectInput but not the label:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a `conditonalPanel`? Also, is there a reason you are defining the labels in separate tags instead of using the label argument of `selectInput`?

Comment: @Joris I am unable to use `conditionalPanel` here since the inputs are supplied as a list to a helper function that creates the horizontal form, so wrapping them in `conditionalPanel` throws it off. I am using a separate label tag since I would like the label to appear on the left hand side of the input, as in a horizontal form. Would you know why `selector = $('#month_full').parentsUntil('form.form-horizontal')` didn't work? I thought I had used the `parentsUntil()` method correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only a limited number of ui-elements you want to show/hide, it might be easier to just give the div-elements an `id` attribute and call `shinyjs::toggle` with `id` instead of `selector`. For instance,

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui<- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    tags$form(
        class = "form-horizontal", action="/action_page.php",

        div(id = "div_month_abb",
            class = 'form-group', 
            tags$label(class = 'control-label col-sm-2', `for` = 'month_abb', 'Month (abbr.)'),
            div(
                class = 'col-sm-4', 
                selectInput('month_abb', '', month.abb)
            )
        ), 

        div(id = "div_month_full",
            class = 'form-group', 
            tags$label(class = 'control-label col-sm-2', `for` = 'month_full', 'Month (full)'),
            div(
                class = 'col-sm-4', 
                selectInput('month_full', '', month.name)
            )
        ), 

        checkboxInput('abbr', 'Abbreviated')

    )
)

server<-function(input, output) {

  observe({

       toggle(id = "div_month_abb", condition = input$abbr)

       toggle(id = "div_month_full", condition = !input$abbr)

      })
}


shinyApp(ui,server)
```